# gcc: command line args referenced differently in assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, command-line, x86

I am used to seeing command line arguments referenced by (convention (A)):

```
pushl %ebp  
movl %esp, %ebp  
movl (%ebp), %eax    # argc  
movl 4(%ebp), %ebx   # pointer to argv[0] string      
movl 8($ebp), %ecx   # pointer to argv[1] string
```

Sometimes, I've seen the list start at an offset of 8, and this is not the (main) question. What I've noticed in a program is this translation and reference which I am confused about, to get `argv[1]` (convention (B)):

```
movl 0xc(%ebp), %eax   # pointer to a pointer to argv[0] (argc is at offset 8)  
addl $0x4, %eax    # argv[1] is a pointer at offset 4 from the pointer to argv[0]   
movl (%eax), %eax    # load where it points to, which is the argv[1] string
```

(at offset `16(%ebp)` I see a pointer to an environmental variable)

(1) Is there any reason for this different convention?
(2) Is there a compiler option to force gcc to use what I believe to be the standard convention (A) above?
(3) Is there a reason gcc uses convention (B)?
(4) Why the additional offset of 8?

System info:
- Ubuntu 12.04
- gcc 4.6.3
- compiled with fno-stack-protector

Comment: Where did you get your convention A code? AFAICT it's incorrect, because (in that case) offset `4(%ebp)` is `argv` itself, not `argv[0]`. At `8(%ebp)` is `envp` (the environment block).

Comment: Also (adding a new comment because editing seems bork'd), the offset of 8 is because at the time `movl %esp, %ebp` is executed, the first two items on the stack are `%ebp` and the return address - each being 4 bytes, thus the 8-byte offset.

Comment: @Drew McGowen: convention A is what you'll see in any assembly tutorial/ book/class, and it works fine when I code with gas which does the gcc assembly. As to the 8, why store a ret address if this is main? (the 4 from pushing ebp were stupid by me, should have noticed).

Comment: @gnometorule: there needs to be a return address from `main()` because `main()` can return to the runtime that called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with a program that has been linked to the C runtime, then the `argc` and `argv` parameters are passed (assuming x86) with `argc` at  `ebp+8` and `argv` at `ebp+12`.  that's because the C runtime performs it's own initialization and passes the arguments to `main()` using the normal C ABI.

The calling convention that you say you're used to seeing (with `argc` at the top of the stack, followed by `argv[0]`..`argv[argc]`) is the state of the stack as set up by the Linux system call that starts a new program.

Note that your assembly oriented code example:

```
pushl %ebp  
movl %esp, %ebp  
movl (%ebp), %eax    # argc  
movl 4(%ebp), %ebx   # pointer to argv[0] string      
movl 8($ebp), %ecx   # pointer to argv[1] string
```

looks to be off by 4 for each of the last three lines because of the initial `pushl` instruction.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and you are correct that what I typed would be off if I first pushl %ebp.

Comment: Shouldn't that `$` be a `%` on the last line?

Comment: Oh also, would this still be true for 64 asm? Or would `argc` be at `rbp+16`, and `argv` at `rbp+24`?

Comment: The offsets are broken.  You pushed EBP before `mov %esp, %ebp`, so `(%ebp)` is the useless saved EBP value.  (Useless because this is `_start` and you aren't returning to a caller.)