# Function arguments in x86-64 asm

Tags: linux, assembly, command-line, x86-64, calling-convention

So I have to do this project for school that consists of reading a file in brainfuck and interpret it as assembly. The code works if I save the file path as a String inside the .data section, but what I want to have it so it gets the file path as an argument when starting the code in the terminal.

I have tried popping 3 times(since the stack should be number of args/ addres of program/ first arg), and then setting %rdi to the value at the adress of the 3rd popped item, but it returns "./interpreter" instead of the file path

This is the code that works:

```
.data
filePath: .asciz "brainF.b"
fileRead: .asicz "r"

.text
.global main
main:
    call fileReader #moves filePath to %rdi, fileRead to %rsi, calls fopen and reads the file
    #code that grabs the read string and interprets it
```

but what I want is:

```
.data
fileRead: .asciz "r"

.text
.global main
main:
    #get 1st argument from terminal(file path) and store it in %rdi
    call fileReader #moves fileRead to %rsi, calls fopen and reads the file
```

and here's how I have to compile and link(this part can't be changed, that's how my teacher wants me to do it):

```
gcc -o interpreter interpreter.s
./interpreter brainF.b
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc: command line args referenced differently in assembly code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204494/gcc-command-line-args-referenced-differently-in-assembly-code)

Comment: The bottom of the stack is always the return address, because the caller has to push args *before* executing a `call` instruction.  (And args are only on the stack in the 32bit x86 ABI anyway.)  You could more usefully poke around with a debugger to see what's in memory where, instead of actually writing trial-and-error code.  Of course, the x86-64 ABI is well documented, see the links at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 64 bit calling convention passes first 6 function arguments in registers, so `argc` is in `rdi` and `argv` is in `rsi`. The first command line argument is `argv[1]` so to access that you need to load `8(%rsi)`:

```
.globl main
main:
    subq $8, %rsp           # align stack
    movq 8(%rsi), %rsi      # fetch argv[1]
    leaq fmt(%rip), %rdi    # format string
    xorl %eax, %eax         # no xmm used
    call printf             # print
    xorl %eax, %eax         # zero return value
    addq $8, %rsp           # restore stack
    ret                     # done

.data
fmt: .string "First argument is %s\n"
```

---

```
$ ./a.out foo bar
First argument is foo
```

Of course you should check `argc` to see if you received enough arguments.